# Overriding error GSNRecipient Contract

Tags: openzeppelin

Edit: I just saw that in the IRelayRecipient.sol contract there are those methods too, so should I just ignore the docs and not include them in the contract?

as suggest before, I'm trying to use a GSN to manage the fees of my contract.

I'm building a matic faucet so that's the only way I can think of to let the user interact with the SC without spending their tokens.

I'm getting a "Overriding function is missing override specifier" error on my acceptRelayedCall(), _preRelayedCall() and post_RelayedCall() methods.

What am I missing?

```
pragma solidity 0.7.6;
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v3.4.0/contracts/GSN/GSNRecipient.sol";

contract Faucet is GSNRecipient {
    
    address public owner;
    constructor(){
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
    
    event tokenTrasferiti(address _to);
    event tokenNonTrasferiti(address _to);
        
    
    function getBalanceOfAddress(address _address) public view returns(uint){
        return _address.balance;
    }
    
    function sendMoney() public payable {
    }
    function withdrawMoney(address payable _to) public {
        if(getBalanceOfAddress(_to) < 50000000000000000)
        {
        _to.transfer(50000000000000000);
        emit tokenTrasferiti(_to);
        }
        else emit tokenNonTrasferiti(_to);
    }

    receive() external payable{
        sendMoney();
    }
    
     function acceptRelayedCall(
        address relay,
        address from,
        bytes calldata encodedFunction,
        uint256 transactionFee,
        uint256 gasPrice,
        uint256 gasLimit,
        uint256 nonce,
        bytes calldata approvalData,
        uint256 maxPossibleCharge
    ) external view returns (uint256, bytes memory) {
        return _approveRelayedCall();
    }

    // We won't do any pre or post processing, so leave _preRelayedCall and _postRelayedCall empty
    function _preRelayedCall(bytes memory context) internal returns (bytes32) {
    }

    function _postRelayedCall(bytes memory context, bool, uint256 actualCharge, bytes32) internal {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the keyword "override"

It should be:

```
function acceptRelayedCall(...) external view override returns (uint256, bytes memory) {
        return _approveRelayedCall();
    }

function _preRelayedCall(bytes memory context) internal returns (bytes32) {
    }

    function _postRelayedCall(bytes memory context, bool, uint256 actualCharge, bytes32) internal {
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give me a brief explanation on why we need to do that? I mean, those methods are identical to the ones in the IrelayRecipient.sol. what's the point in overriding a method with the same function

Comment: @LeonardoD'Amico it is not compulsory to override and it's upon what kind of functionality you need, but if you do then you have to use the keyword `override`. more at: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/contracts.html#function-overriding